How do I reshape data to longer format using Postgresql?
I am working with a Postgresql database where the data is shaped like this:



A_a
B_a
A_b
B_b




4
3
4
5


2
5
3
1



How would I reshape or pivot it so that it is in a longer format like below?



upper_case
lower_case
value




A
a
4


A
a
2


B
a
3


B
a
5


A
b
4


A
b
3


B
b
5


B
b
1



Thank you!

One method is UNION 4 queries... select 'A' as upper_case, 'a' as lower_case, "A_a" as value from table1 union... etc.

Since it is safe to go from columns to rows, I would flip the data to JSON and then pull it back over like so:
select split_part(k,'_', 1) as upper_case, 
       split_part(k,'_', 2) as lower_case, 
       value::int
from shape1 
cross join lateral jsonb_each_text(to_jsonb(shape1)) as e(k,value)
order by lower_case, upper_case

Working fiddle
